# Show output of a perl script in linux

Tags: linux, perl

I am  using a web interface written in php that runs a perl script in a linux environment.It passes parameters(username,password,...) to the script . I want to view the output of the script without interfering with the process. Note that the script in his turn also passes data and excutes another program.

The script contains print commands like

> `if( $@ ){
>           print "Error :".$@."\n";
>           print "skip...\n";    }
>       else{
>       }`

I just want to view these results from the shell, also it would do it if i can save into a txt file .

thanks a lot!

Comment: And your question is...? Also, probably would be helpful if you provide _any_ details about the "web interface" you are using.

Comment: while the script is running you can read /proc/<pid>/fd/1 for stdout and /proc/<pid>/fd/2 for stderr, <pid> is script's process ID

Comment: The question is very unclear and missing many details. [Edit the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/10995223/edit) to improve it. Do you want to watch the progress of the Perl program via the PHP-generated Web page, or do you want to call the Perl program from the shell and watch the progress in the shell? What is the output of the Perl program, or else how do you determine its progress? Can you change the Perl program to add callbacks? Show your PHP/Perl code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the Perl program from the shell to see the output from `print`.

```
$ perl theprogram
⋮
Error : blah blah
skip...
⋮
```

Redirect [STDOUT](http://enwp.org/stdout) to save it into a file.

```
$ perl theprogram > theprogram.log
```

These are the very basics of shell usage, you already should know all this if you are a programmer. If not, read a Unix book for beginners.

Comment: Thanks @daxim ! i'm no programmer ;)

I need to redirect the output without executing the script, how can i do this?

Comment: You can't, because the output is generated by the script.